# How to prevent Symfony2 from escaping html

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am working on a website with symfony2, and in the back office I want to add a html code to include a player.
I am using the `raw` function with twig to get the html, but the problem is when I enter the html code Symfony is escaping the quotes. 
How can I avoid that and make symfony record the raw html?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In fact it has nothing to do with symfony, it was just because of the magic_quotes. I disabled them in the htaccess and everything is fine.